# Start React Native App using Intent

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent

I am trying to start a react native app from another Android App using Intent.Say for example I have following code to start a

App 1 activity(with help of android docs):-

```
Intent sendIntent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra("Order No", datauri);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = 
getCurrentActivity().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(sendIntent, 
0);
Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), 
title);
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, 
targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[targetedShareIntents.size()]));
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Now in React Native App have the following Manifest file to recieve such intents:-

```
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
```

And now i am able to start the second App but how do i get the value passed from App 1.